# Series I(1) python

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I have a df with stocks for 25 years and i am trying to keep only the I(1) one.

I want to store the new value in dfi
threshold = 5%

```
import statsmodels.tsa.stattools as stm
```

First i create a list with the name of my columns :

```
dflist = list(dftest.columns.values)
```

then i do this :

```
for dfi in dftest:
    if stm.adfuller(df.loc[:,dflist][1] < threspvalue or stm.adfuller(df.loc[:,dflist].diff(1).dropna())[1] > threspvalue:
         dflist.remove(dfi)
```

Any idea on how to do it correctly?

Edit : I have this error code "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" with the arrow under stm line 2.

Edit 2 :I did this and managed to have something

```
stockremoved = []
threspvalue = 0.05
for dfi in dflist:
    if stm.adfuller(df.loc[:,dfi])[1] < threspvalue or stm.adfuller(df.loc[:,dfi].diff(1).dropna())[1] > threspvalue:
        dflist.remove(dfi)
        stockremoved.append(dfi)
```

Comment: This is a bit outside my area, but it may help those who understand what you're doing if you describe exactly what your given code is doing incorrectly.

Comment: You are modifying the list in the for loop while iterating over it, which can have unexpected consequences.